# How can I open sublime text 2 with a specified directory in the file viewer panel?

Tags: sublime-text

I know I can launch sublime from the command line with `subl`, but how do I open it with the current directory I'm in appearing in the file viewer panel on the left?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a file name or directory to the `subl` command without any extra arguments. For example, to open the current directory in the sidebar, just run:

```
subl .
```

To open a specific file, just pass its name:

```
subl ~/.bashrc
```

Run `subl --help` to get a summary of command-line options.